# Spotlight not finding .app created with appify

Tags: spotlight, homebrew, symlink, alias

I've used a script called appify described here https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps to create `/Applications/Emacs.app` that runs the actual Emacs.app at `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.4/Emacs.app` installed by Homebrew. I did this because Spotlight was not indexing the symlink I previously had, and while it did index the Finder alias, it was quite down there in the search results, which is far from idea for launching an app frequently.

Is there anything special that the Spotlight indexer expects from an .app container in order for it to be allowed to be indexed?